# Lambda expression with .Where clause using Contains

Tags: c#, lambda, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

When connecting to CRM 2013 is there a smart way to create a lambda expression that gets the entities who's GUID are in a List.

This code breaks on the Where clause and gives the error:

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

Code:

```
    private List<UserInformationProxy> GetContactsFromGuidList(List<Guid> contactList)
    {
        var result = _serviceContext.ContactSet
            .Where(x=> contactList.Contains((Guid) x.ContactId)) // this line breaks
            .Select(x => new UserInformationProxy()
            {
                FullName = x.FullName,
                Id = x.ContactId
            })
            .Distinct()
            .ToList<UserInformationProxy>();

        return result;
    }

    // return class
    public class UserInformationProxy
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string DomainName { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently I'm solving this by getting all the contacts from the ContactSet and sorting out the ones I want with a loop in my code. This works, but is quite slow as I need to get all 10000 contacts instead of sending the Guids of the 40 Im actually interested in to the SQL server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881302/equivalent-to-sql-in-clause)

Comment: The linked answer does not have a solution for this specific problem. The Dynamic LINQ does not seem to work for Guid's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QueryExpressions support an In operator, so this should work just fine:

```cs
private List<UserInformationProxy> GetContactsFromGuidList(List<Guid> contactList)
{
    var qe = new QueryExpression(Contact.EntityLogicalName);
    qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname", "contactid")
    qe.Criteria.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.In, list.Cast<Object>().ToArray());
    qe.Distinct = true;

    var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe).Entities.Select (e => e.ToEntity<Contact>()).
        Select(x => new UserInformationProxy()
        {
            FullName = x.FullName,
            Id = x.ContactId
        });

    return results;
}
```

On a side note, every Contact has to have an Id that is not empty, so there is no need to check for it.

Comment: The code compiled but threw this error: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:query. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 10724. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'System.Collections.Generic:List`1'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. .

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt sorry, we have some extension method that make this code easier and I attempted to do it off of my head.  I've updated my answer with the correct that handles the conversion from List to Object[].  I tested it, so it should work :)  The `AddCondition` accepts an params object[], and the list gets treated as a single object, rather than a list, so the call to cast it as an object, and then convert to an array fixes the issue.

Comment: As a side note, you need to add the columns you want to work with to the QueryExpression, ie: qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname", "contactid"); or you will just get null values back.

Comment: Thanks @Daryl for sharing this information, I knew the `In` clause but I didn't think it works also with the record Guid

Comment: @GuidoPreite No Prob!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: It is possible to accomplish using a single query, Daryl posted an answer with the right code.

Other (not so clever) alternatives are:

1. Retrieve all the records and after check the Guids
2. Do a single retrieve for each Guid

Because are only 40 records, I suggest to use late-bound to retrieve the records, in order to choose the minimal ColumnSet.

Useful links related to this issue:

- [Another question regarding Dynamics CRM LINQ limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708156/invalid-crm-2011-linq-query-invalid-where-condition-an-entity-member-is-inv)
- [Performance test Early Bound vs Late Bound](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/crm-2011-early-binding-vs-late-binding-performance/)

Comment: When would you say the performance breakpoint for doing single retrieve for every post compared to get all and do the sorting in code is?

Comment: It's not easy to determinate the breakpoint, but I suggested using late-bound because it is faster than early-bound for few records as in your case, you can find an analysis here: http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/crm-2011-early-binding-vs-late-binding-performance/